# Rstudio program coding

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the ARDL model to regress multiple time series variable. I logged my original data set, and made sure there were no negative numbers that were logged. This is my regression model:

```
tsmodel2 <- dynlm(LN_LFT ~ L(LN_LFT,1) + LN_LFL + L(LN_LFL,1) + LN_LIP + L(LN_LIP,1) + 
                  LN_LI_PSEdu + L(LN_LI_PSEdu,1), 
                  data = tsLN_D)
```

this model gives me the numbers I need. BUT, when I add another variable, which is GDP per capita (in USD):

```
tsmodel3 <- dynlm(LN_LFT ~ L(LN_LFT,1) + LN_LFL + L(LN_LFL,1) + LN_LIP + L(LN_LIP,1) + 
                  LN_LI_PSEdu + L(LN_LI_PSEdu,1) + LN_CGDP + L(LN_CGDP,1), 
                  data = tsLN_D)
```

...I get this error message:

> Warning message:
> In qt(alpha, df = df.residual(model)) : NaNs produced

I know NaN represents Not a Number but I don't understand why it's giving me this error. I even checked using the code `which(is.na(tsLN_D))` and it said I don't have any NaNs present in the dataset.

Please help me solve this problem as I need to use the data for my thesis. If you need any additional information, I can post it.

EDIT: when I remove one of the 5 independent variables, the error disappears. It only appears when I run all 5 together

Comment: `is.na()` doesn't check for NaN (not a number), it checks for NA (missing/not available). The warning says NaN was **produced** - by some calculation - not that they were present in the dataset. You'll get better help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(tsLN_D)`, if that is not too large. Also include all the relevant code including libraries (where does `dynlm` come from?)

Comment: The libraries that I loaded to use the dynlm function: library(ARDL), library(vars), library(dLagM), library(tseries), & library(dynamic).                                                                                
The data set has multiple variables in it so I'll see if it fits in here: 'year <- c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021)' , and the variable that's giving me a problem is 'LN_CGDP <- c(10.86329162, 
10.87178403, 10.8711399, 10.83871776, 10.68272379, 10.65291118, 
10.71728985, 10.74823492, 10.74449753, 10.67705455, 10.86587189)'

Comment: the other variables are: (LFT is the dependent variable)                                     'LN_LFT <- 9.834683949, 9.845360434, 9.856118129, 9.858824859, 
9.864871457, 9.871584004, 9.88625492, 9.897660609, 9.917138947, 
9.902116613, 9.927404254 '                                                                                These are independent variables: 'LN_LFL <- 8.276750876, 8.302340178, 8.32828197, 8.348372092, 8.377586237, 8.433746363, 8.454125588, 8.496439312, 8.546208156, 8.538915543, 8.613248548'

Comment: continuation for independent variables: 'LN_LIP <- 8.753545127, 8.765723748, 8.79612711, 8.827028069, 8.84219995, 
8.89153908, 8.901775089, 8.937507502, 8.977398978, 8.992905495, 
9.032480846' , 'LN_LI_PSEdu <- 7.431536614, 7.430825629, 
7.457089824, 7.476529005, 7.507031244, 7.544649518, 7.551291959, 
7.601652178, 7.632643345, 7.60698393, 7.69288894'

Comment: Please don't add code or data to comments. You should edit your question to inclure the relevant details so they can be properly formatted. For tips on how to include data in your question see [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: sorry, I will note that! thank you